# Is it possible to read a base64 url in the iframe tag?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm looking for a way to "mask" the url of a youtube video, like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{base64_encode($video-
>demo_src)}}" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-
picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

> $video->demo_src is a full urls(https://www.youtube.com/embed/JyCoMhjrRuA)...

Is there a way to display the video without showing the real URL?

Comment: Why do you want to make the video URL unavailable? Do you want to prevent downloading of the file? Do you want to give access only to authorised people?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to display the video without showing the real URL?

No.

The browser has to make a request to the URL in order to get the content for it.

The browser belongs to the user.

The user has full control over the browser.

The developer tools in the browser provide several ways to determine what URL is requested.

Even if you obfuscate it, it is *utterly* trivial for a user to get the deobfuscated URL.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is encode with PHP and decode via Js:

Encode PHP:

```
<input type="hidden" id="url" value="{{base64_encode($course->demo_src)}}"/>
```

Get url via JS:

```
<script>
  var video = document.getElementById("url").value;
</script>
```

Now create a Js file and past this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var Base64 = {

    // private property
    _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

    // public method for encoding
    encode: function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

        while (i < input.length) {

            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output = output +
                this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
                this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

        }

        return output;
    },

    // public method for decoding
    decode: function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        while (i < input.length) {

            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }

        }

        output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

        return output;

    },

    // private method for UTF-8 encoding
    _utf8_encode: function (string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        var utftext = "";

        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }

        }

        return utftext;
    },

    // private method for UTF-8 decoding
    _utf8_decode: function (utftext) {
        var string = "";
        var i = 0;
        var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

        while (i < utftext.length) {

            c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

            if (c < 128) {
                string += String.fromCharCode(c);
                i++;
            }
            else if ((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                i += 2;
            }
            else {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
                c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 2);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                i += 3;
            }

        }

        return string;
    }

}

url = Base64.decode(video);

$('#iframe').attr('src', url);

});
```

Iframe:

The front-end result will display a base64 encoding; This isn't a security way, but makes access to url defficult.

Comment: "but makes access to url defficult" — It really doesn't since you are writing it back to the DOM so is visible in the DOM inspector and the browser has to make a request to it, so it is visible in the Network inspector.

Comment: Base64 is **not** encryption